# Git revert back to a certain commit

Tags: git

I want to revert my code back to a certain commit. I do not want the changes to stay either.
This is the commit id which I want to go back to.

`a7f9f64c2df1b6133656955f9049d68d6e8cd261`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code will permanently undo all your changes after this commit.

`git reset --hard a7f9f64c2df1b6133656955f9049d68d6e8cd261`